# (SQL) Relational design issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, relational-database, entity-relationship

I am making a sample reservation application using SQL, where users purchase tickets for events, where each event has a location and a performer.

So far, I was planning on making a large events table, where each row has the performer, location, number of tickets, and also a key referencing a ticket table per individual event. Those event-specific ticket tables will have rows containing event_ID, customer_ID, and ticket number.

Locations, Performers, and Customer details will be their own tables.

The only issue is if a customer wants to query for which tickets he owns, it would have to search every event ticket table for their customer_ID.  The only other thing I can think of is have a tiny table tied to each customer containing just the ticket numbers they've purchased, but I was hoping there would be other ways that I'm not thinking of to avoid duplication.

How can I optimize such a service model to make all its features as efficient as possible?  (Specifically the [customer]->[tickets owned] query)

Thanks

Comment: The answer is not to have multiple event specific tables.  When you divide the same data over multiple tables, your queries immediately get complicated and maintenance is a huge pain.  What sql platform are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I think you answered your own question.  A separate table of tickets for each event doesn't seem like the way to go.  You want one table of tickets, that has a column for the `EventId` as well as other information.

In general, if you have a data model where adding an additional entity requires adding a table, then you  don't have a good data model.  In your case, adding a new event would require adding a new event-ticket table for the event.  If performance is an issue, relational databases have lots of facilities for improving the performance of queries on large tables.

Some of the problems of adding tables instead of rows:

- Partially filled database pages can start to eat up lots of disk space and local page caches, and have exactly the opposite effect of what you want.
- Looking at data across events requires bringing together a variable number of tables that change over time.
- Modifications to the database require changing lots of tables.
- Access control over the data (security) has to be replicated over all the tables.

Comment: So there is no issue with just having one tickets table, even if it is going to be one gigantic table with 100,000+ entries?

Comment: @user17259 . . . 100,000 rows is not a "big" table.  SQL can support many millions and even billions of rows.  You will probably want indexes to improve performance.

Comment: @user17259, I agree with Gordon Linoff that proper indexing will provide good performance regardless of table size.  One way to thing about it is that you'll get the same performance regardless of size as long as you touch only those rows needed by the query.  Useful indexes allow you to do that.  I work with billion row tables and queries are sub-second thanks to attention to index and query tuning detail.

Comment: Also would querying the tickets table for tickets a certain customer owns be good enough? It would be like 1 or 2 tickets on average per person to lookup in the table.

Comment: You would want an index on the customer column in that table.